# Call code before view loads objective C

Tags: objective-c

How can I execute code before the viewDidLoad method please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute code in -(id)init, you have to pay attention when you use some codes like self.view.frame = .... or [self.view addSubView:xxx] inside -(id)init, it will load view and run -(void)viewDidLoad method before -(id)init return.

If you made your view with IB, then a method named -(void)awakeFromNib; would be called when your codes load view from IB. If you made view by codes, you can put those codes inside -(void)loadView to construct the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The correct place depends on what exactly you want to do. You could put it in the correct `-init...` method or the class initializer `+initialize`. Or maybe you want to do this before you load your view.

Comment: I want to get data from a webservice and parse, etc before I load my view so I can load the view using this data